# Total Permutations / Combinations on Multiple Dice Throws?

Tags: combinatorics

I am knowing the total number of permutations / combinations on coin tosses is given as: Total = 2^n where n equal the number of permutables (quarters tossed). What about dice? Suppose I repeatedly toss two dice with two sides, three dice with four sides and four dice with six sides in the air. 2d2 + 3d4 + 4d6 Is the correct expression (Mathematica) given by:
Total[{{2^2}*{3^4}*{4^6}}]

Comment: the answer is (2*2*4*4*4*6*6*6*6)^n  for n throws or (2^2*4^3*6^4)^n

Comment: Thanks for your efforts on my behalf. What do you mean by the lower case letter n on the right hand side of the parenthesis? Before you reply, you might want to left click your way to the AnyDice web site. Jasper Flick's software calculates everything I need except totals.

Answer (score 1):

When you have multiple independent events, the number of possibilities is the product of the number of possibilities for each event.  This is where the $2^n$ comes from in throwing $n$ coins.  There are two possibilities for each toss.  So for throwing a three sided die, two four sided dice, and three six sided dice, the number of ordered possibilities is $3 \cdot 4^2 \cdot 6^3$